# How to get http request header with ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I want to get request header's cookie.

But, I couldn't find any satisfactory document.

plz, Tell me a good way

Comment: Could you please provide more details?

Comment: did you try document.cookie?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to access page headers via client JavaScript but you can get these request headers on your server side and then pass them into your React app.

```js
const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
     fetch(Some_API).then(response => {
         console.log(response.headers)
     })
  }, [])
}
```

or you can use `axios`